# Regex Not Supposed To Run In Link Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Currently, I am writing regular expressions to parse a textarea for BBCode, and replace it with HTML.

The problem at the moment is that the regex I use to replace all URLs, is replacing URLs in the `[link]` tag a second time and messing them up.

I am currently replacing all `[link=___]test[/link]` tags like so:

```
.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|\[(link=)((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/link\]/gi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6) { return g1 ? g1 : '<a href="' + g3 + '">' + g6 + '</a>'; })
```

And then I am replacing all URLs with themselves in a `<a>` tag like so:

```
.replace(/(\[(code|link=(.*))\][\s\S]*?\[\/(code|link)\])|((http|https):\/\/[\S]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)/gi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5) { return g1 ? g1 : '<a href="' + g5 + '">' + g5 + '</a>'; })
```

I do not know how to *not* make the second regex parse URLs and *not* change them if they are already inside of a `<link>` tag. Any ideas on how to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a check if there is a closing angle bracket and a closing `</a>` node. If missing, we are not inside the opening `<a>` tag.

Here is your 2nd modified regex that checks the above conditions with a negative look-ahead `(?![^<]*>[^<]*<\/a>)`:

```
(\[(code|link=(.*))\][\s\S]*?\[\/(code|link)\])|((http|https):\/\/[^\s<>]{0,2000}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(\/[^\[\]\<\>]*)?)(?![^<]*>[^<]*<\/a>)
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU3kJ0/1)

In case you have opening and closing nodes in separate string, we'd need to reverse the regex and use a [look-behind workaround "through reversal"](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).

Comment: :) Check the end of the regex, the negative look-ahead is making sure there are no non-`<`s, then `>`, then non-`<`s, then `</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you take this for a spin:

```
.replace(/(?:\[link=([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[\/link\])|(https?:\/\/[^\s]+\.[a-z]{2,})/gi, function(a,b,c) { if (typeof b === 'undefined') { return '<a href="'+a+'">'+a+'</a>'; } return '<a href="'+b+'">'+c+'</a>';})
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnvnryLm/)

Your original code also did something with `[code]` but since that wasn't referenced in your description, I left it out. If you need something done with those as well please clarify what exactly.

Comment: Yes, Code is a MUST. That is so it does not highlight URLs in `[code]` tags.